# APK created using EAS-CLI crashing on physical device before splash screen without any errors

Tags: java, android, react-native, expo

I am using Expo bare workflow for creating the react-native app. The App development and testing are working perfectly on IOS.
But, on android, while doing development I can run app with dev-client with the command
expo run: android
And when I have created an APK using the command
eas build --profile production --platform android
it gets created without errors but upon installation on a physical device, the app crashes before the splash screen.
My eas.json is

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.1.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"        
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

`adb logcat logs`

```bash
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest: Could not read embedded manifest
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest: java.io.FileNotFoundException: app.manifest
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:860)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:837)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at expo.modules.updates.manifest.EmbeddedManifest.get(EmbeddedManifest.kt:22)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderTask.launchFallbackUpdateFromDisk(LoaderTask.kt:238)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderTask.start(LoaderTask.kt:99)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController.start(UpdatesController.kt:290)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController$Companion.initialize(UpdatesController.kt:464)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesPackage$createReactNativeHostHandlers$handler$1.onWillCreateReactInstanceManager(UpdatesPackage.kt:41)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:27)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at com.sudarshan_007.SampleApp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:66)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1189)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6603)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:235)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E EmbeddedManifest:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sudarshan_007.SampleApp, PID: 22600
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.AssertionError: The embedded manifest is invalid or could not be read. Make sure you have configured expo-updates correctly in android/app/build.gradle. app.manifest
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.updates.manifest.EmbeddedManifest.get(EmbeddedManifest.kt:31)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderTask.launchFallbackUpdateFromDisk(LoaderTask.kt:238)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderTask.start(LoaderTask.kt:99)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController.start(UpdatesController.kt:290)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController$Companion.initialize(UpdatesController.kt:464)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesPackage$createReactNativeHostHandlers$handler$1.onWillCreateReactInstanceManager(UpdatesPackage.kt:41)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:27)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:42)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.sudarshan_007.SampleApp.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:66)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1189)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6603)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:235)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
10-17 11:05:21.911 22600 22600 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
```

I checked in `android` folder  for `AndroidManifest.XML` file it is there but still it throws the error

`package.json`

```json
{
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "android": "react-native run-android",
      "ios": "react-native run-ios",
      "web": "expo start --web",
      "start": "expo start --dev-client",
      "prebuild": "expo prebuild"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@expo-google-fonts/cinzel": "^0.2.2",
      "@expo-google-fonts/cinzel-decorative": "^0.2.2",
      "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
      "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
      "axios": "^0.25.0",
      "expo": "~46.0.9",
      "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
      "expo-auth-session": "~3.7.1",
      "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
      "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
      "expo-gl": "~11.4.0",
      "expo-random": "~12.3.0",
      "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
      "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
      "expo-three": "^6.0.1",
      "expo-three-orbit-controls": "^2.0.0",
      "expo-updates": "~0.14.5",
      "gsap-rn": "^0.0.15",
      "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
      "moment": "^2.29.4",
      "react": "18.0.0",
      "react-dom": "18.0.0",
      "react-native": "0.69.5",
      "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
      "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.1",
      "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
      "react-native-purchases": "^5.0.2",
      "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
      "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.3",
      "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
      "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
      "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
      "react-native-webview": "11.23.0",
      "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
      "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
      "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.11.2",
      "three": "^0.127.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.18.6"
    },
    "private": true,
    "name": "SampleApp",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  }
```

Comment: Found a similar question for react-native project
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944572/where-should-app-manifest-be-found-in-a-react-native-project

But, does this same applies to projects created with `expo`

Comment: I think the manifest here related to `app.json`/`app.config.js` not `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: ok and do we have solution for this issue ?

Comment: Upvoted, we have the exact same issue. We're migrating to EAS and this is blocking us. I've created an issue at https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19721